# Is $X^TAX$ p.s.d if $A$ is p.s.d?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

Is $X^TAX$ positive semi-definite if $A$ is positive semi-definite? All matrices are real-valued. I am interested in both cases when i) $X$ is rectangular matrix ii) $X$ is square matrix.

Comment: Note that $\langle X^tAXv,v\rangle = \langle AXv, Xv\rangle = \langle Ay,y\rangle \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is $n\times n$ and $X$ is $n\times m$, then for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$ we have
$$ v^TX^TAXv=(Xv)^TA(Xv)\geq 0$$
since $A$ is assumed to be positive semidefinite. Therefore $X^TAX$ is positive semidefinite as well.